# I am unable to convert an ArrayBuffer stored in DB to an image

Tags: javascript, react-native

My app takes a photo which is converted to an ArrayBuffer and stored in DB as such. I want to then retrieve that data and convert it to an image without storing the resulting file.

I have looked RN-Fetch-blob and FileReader but am unclear about a few things.

Here is what I've tried with variable combinations after reading many different posts on the issue:

```
var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array(expense.receipt);
const blob = new Blob(expense.receipt,"image/jpeg" ); 
//const blob = new Blob([expense.receipt],"image/jpeg" ); <-error
 //const blob = new Blob(arrayBufferView,"image/jpeg" ); <-error

//console.log (blob);
const fileReaderInstance = new FileReader();
fileReaderInstance.readAsDataURL(blob);  // tried 'readAsBufferArray' but RN complained that that function is not implemented.
fileReaderInstance.onload = () => {
 const base64data = fileReaderInstance.result;                
 console.log(base64data);
};
 var imageBase64 = 'data:'+"image/jpeg"+';base64,'+blob;
 console.log (imageBase64)
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `const blob = new Blob([arrayBufferView],{type:"image/jpeg"} );` can you try this

Comment: Yes! thank you :) Perhaps you'd like to post this as an answer and I can give you some of that good ol correct answer karma?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converting an image from **Array Buffer** to:

**Blob:**

```
var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array(expense.receipt);
const blob = new Blob([arrayBufferView], {type:"image/jpeg"} );
const img = createObjectURL(blob); //Remember to revokeObjectURL when done
```

**Base64:**

```
var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array(expense.receipt);
const charArr = arrayBufferView.reduce((data, byte)=> (data + String.fromCharCode(byte)), ''));
const img = btoa(charArr);
```

Comment: Thank you for this! In your opinion can you comment on which is better?

Comment: I think blob. Its not bulky as base64 and you don't have to hold as a primitive string variable like you have to do with base64 string. One concern with blob is you have to manually unload images when you are done.